# I'm getting ClassCastException in below code in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

```java
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {   
     public void run() {
        Screen screen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();
        System.out.println("Screen == "+screen);    
        if (screen instanceof PushNotificationsScreen) {
            System.out.println("Push Notification Screen");    
            PushNotificationsScreen pns = (PushNotificationsScreen) screen; 
            pns.update();    
        }   
    }   
});
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure **that** is where you're getting this exception?  Looking at the code, I don't see how that's possible.  You test `screen instanceof PushNotificationsScreen`, which is the right thing to do.

Comment: yes, at the time of debugging I found exception in that peace of code.

Comment: Mypeace of code ---> System.out.println("going to show the notification screen");                                       try{                 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){   public void run(){                                             Screen screen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen(); if(screen instanceof PushNotificationsScreen){ PushNotificationsScreen pns = (PushNotificationsScreen) screen; pns.update();}}});}
catch(Exception e){                                         System.out.println("Exception test "+e);         e.printStackTrace(); }

Comment: Add more logging to see if execution proceeds past the one cast in your code.  Your current logging doesn't isolate the problem - pns.update() could just as easily throw a ClassCastException

Comment: Are you running this code in the background application? If yes, then UiApplication.getUiApplication() will give you a class cast. Also, instead of catching the Exception, catch a Throwable. Then do Alt+LGLG to open the event viewer and get the stack trace.